# WiX Burn Bootstrapper - Can't detect registry key

Tags: windows, wix, registry, 64-bit, wix3.6

I'm installing a product that requires the Visual C++ redistributables (x64). First my bootstrapper attempts to detect if vcredist (x64) is already installed...

```
<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\VC\Runtimes\x64" Value="Installed" Variable="vcredist"/>
```

The key is 'virtualized' (I think), in regedit it appears under...

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\VC\Runtimes\x64
```

Notice I don't put the 'Wow6432Node' bit in my search because I think that's meant to be hidden by the OS?.  This search ALWAYS fails....

```
[131C:0BC0][2013-03-18T12:42:17]: Registry key not found. Key = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\VC\Runtimes\x64'
```

I tried adding `Win64="yes"` to my registry search, no success. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you need to check to see if is already installed? Just redist the MSVCRT MSM and have your MSI install it. If the same version is installed, it will be detected by the installed itself. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956747/c-sharp-missing-msvcr100-dll/6963678#6963678

Comment: The reason I check is to avoid having to download vcredist unless it's actually needed. I update my software often, so it's painful for the end-users to have to download and reinstall vcredist every week.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want your search to look like this:

```
<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\VC\Runtimes\x64"
                     Value="Installed" Variable="vcredist"/>
```

You're current code is searching for a key named `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` under HKLM. I doubt that exists. ;)

Comment: So obvious in hindsight ;) Thanks!